# I am using Ubuntu, XAMPP, MySQL, and Geany. Trouble using fopen();

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu, backend

So when I try to use:

```
fopen("sometext.txt", "w") or die("blahblahbla");
```

I keep on getting the following message:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied". I have looked for other
>   answers on this site and none of them actually work.

Why is this doing this? Can somebody recommend a fix?

Do I have permission to create files in my directory? I get a bunch of advice on using `chmod` or changing the "file access", but **how** do you do this? They never explain that, just "oh use this or that".

Answer (score 0):

If you have Terminal Access just fire a command in file's folder:
sudo chmod 777 sometext.txt ( For security reasons, later use correct chmod for permission)
if you dont have, you can modify File Attributes in your FTP client. ( Tick all fields (Execute-read-write) for Owner, Group, Everyone).

I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are in the `apache` group (check it with `id username`), then add your user to group `apache` (`sudo usermod -G apache -a username`) and then make sure the directory is in the group `apache` (check it with `ls -l directory`. I suppose the directory is `/var/www/html` or `/srv/whatever`, but XAMPP has its own. If not, do a `sudo chgrp apache directory`. Also, the directory must be writable by group members (`chmod g+w directory`).

Obviously in the apache configuration must be the apache user and group. If they doesn't exist, create them (`sudo groupadd apache` and `sudo useradd apache`).

P.S: `chmod 777` is **evil!** It's better to be in the `apache` group and avoid making your file be edited by someone else!